# Vimeo API v3: restrict search results by author

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I would like to restrict Vimeo v3 search results to a specific author (upload user). Since there doesn't seem to be an author_id filter on search, I'm approaching the other way around - using:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/users/yoshiyoroh/videos?query=ANYWHERE
```

to do a query search of the author's videos. My problem is quite simple - it "doesn't work". Adding a ?query= & and searching a value causes no results to return in the playground:

```
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/users/yoshiyoroh/videos
```

Is this ?query meant to be used differently, or it is possibly a bug in the new API?

TIA for any help!

Comment: This might have been a bug. We are pushing out a possible fix. Contact us at vimeo.com/help/contact if you continue to encounter problems.

Comment: Thank you! I thought as much, and sent it in as a bug report yesterday. will wait to see how it goes

Comment: just check -that worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was due to a bug the Vimeo folks have taken care of - thanks guys!